# Should the vowel also become a bit more open before consonant cluster by conjugation?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

segeln > segle

lesen > lest

Is the e changed from [e] to [ɛ]?

the e in *essen* and *gehen* is different.

Comment: Please add a little more information: Why do you even think this would be the case? Are you referring to a specific variety of German or about German in general (which would make the question too broad, in my opinion)? - As it stands, it seems unanswerable to me.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek I think this is a reasonable question. They are asking why the e's in *lest* and *Rest* are different. And there's a good answer

Comment: @PiedPiper No, sadly the question does not cite _Rest_ as one of the words in question. If it was, it would actually have been a much better question - which would have still been answerable by referring to a dictionary. The question as it stands now does not ask anything useful. Only with very much effort in _guessing_, what the op atually wants, a good answer like Janka's is possible.

Comment: The _also_ in the question suggests, that you know of some cases, where the described behaviour acutally occurs. Can you give examples of a case, where this happens?

Comment: Essen und gehen enthalten jeweils ziemlich genau 2 Es. In Gehen findet sich kein Konsonantencluster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is **no**.

This may seem tricky to you because in words as *der Rest*, *die Pest*, *das Fest* there is indeed an *ɛ*.

BUT, as a basic rule, pronounciation of vowels in stems is stable in German, and if there ever is a vowel change, an *Ablaut*, this substantial change is marked by using a different vowel character/diphthong.

> lesen → sie l**ie**st

Comment: The restriction “as a basic rule” is well put. There are occasional exceptions to this rule. They come from Central German dialects where vowel shortenings before consonant clusters may occur. A few of these have found there way into the standard language, e.g. *geben → gibt.* The regular form *giebt* is no longer used in writing, and I guess that the corresponding pronunciation with a long vowel might only be occasional found in the very South, where original long vowels tend to be preserved more faithfully.